Properties of Bessel functions
Salutations, I'm stuck on how to use the definition of the Bessel functions $J_n(x)$ to show for for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that
$$J_{n\pm1}(x) = \frac{n}{x} J_n(x) \mp J_n'(x). \qquad (1)$$
It is given that $$J\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!\left(n+k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2k},$$
from this I can derive
$$J_{n}'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n+2k\right)}{2}\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!\left(n+k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2k-1}\right).$$
Substituting this into the equation above yields
\begin{align}
J_{n+1}(x)&=\frac{n}{x}J\left(x\right)-J'\left(x\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!\left(n+k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2k}\left(\frac{n}{x}-\frac{\left(n+2k\right)}{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-1}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{a}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!\left(n+k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2k}\left(\frac{-2k}{x}\right)
\end{align}.
I separately found
\begin{align}
J_{n+1}(x)&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!\left(n+1+k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+1+2k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{2\left(n+1+k\right)}\right)\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!\left(n+k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2k}
\end{align}.
I do not see how theses expressions could be equivalent, hence I graphed in desmos and concluded that theses were not equivalent. Am I misreading the $\mp$ and $\pm$ notation or did I make a mistake elsewhere? Any help and direction would be greatly appreciated.

Mathematica evaluations seem to imply they are equivalent as their difference is extremely small which can be attributed to truncation/precision errors in the evaluation.

All of your equations are correct! (Except the upper sum limit should always be $\infty$, not $a$. The reason your desmos graphs don't work out for large $x$ is that you stop the sum at $a=10$. You can make the two plots equal by stopping the first one at $a-1$, then the sums are exactly the same. The upper limit begin $a$ or $a-1$ doesn't matter when you let $a\to\infty$.)
The normal way to show your relation would be from other recurrence relations, which are found by working with the generating function, e.g. as in Arfken and Weber, but let's use your series expansions.
The $k=0$ term from your first expression is zero (from the $-2k$ factor), so we can replace $k$ with $k+1$ in the sum and take it from $k=0$. This is just relabelling the dummy variable.
\begin{align}
J_{n+1}(x)
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!\left(n+k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2k}\left(\frac{-2k}{x}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!\left(n+k+1\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2(k+1)}\left(\frac{-2(k+1)}{x}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac x{2(n+k+1)}\right)\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k!\left(n+k\right)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n+2k}\\
\end{align}
Just as you got. Moral of the story: when comparing power series, look at coefficients for the same power of $x$.
